# List files without permission

Tags: unix

Is there a find command which would list me files that I don't have permissions to?

Looking from man find, I only found examples which print files that me or my group have permissions to.

Any other solution will also do. I am about to rsync data with checksum and with a test transfer I got errors:

`rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]`

sudo not available.

Comment: are you trying to find out the files that you cannot transfer?

Comment: Yes this would be the case.

Comment: rsync would try to create temporary files in the location you want to copy . look for some files that have `.XXXX` suffix.

Comment: or try giving the `-v` option , which will list the files to be transferred.

Comment: Used -v with testing, but how to deal with huge set of files? -v prints output to console which is impossible to track.

Comment: why dont you try redirecting the output to a file?

Answer (score 1):

Listing files you don't have access to, would be a security flaw in the program or OS.
If you required read permissions across all groups, speak to your sys admin.